# Compile time error in assignment statement

Tags: delphi

I have this code:

```
TTimer(TimerList.Items[Row]) := TTimer.Create(Self);
```

When I run the program, there is the following error:

> unit1.pas(70,19) Error: Argument cannot be assigned to

Why is this error thrown and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the type of `TimerList`?

Comment: @J... `TObjectList`

Comment: `System.Contnrs.TObjectList`?  Or a generic `TObjectList<?>`

Comment: @J... The former. I'm just sorting out my code, then I'll run it and accept your answer. Thank you for your time J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including an explicit typecast on the left hand side - this [can be allowed for variables](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Variable_Typecasts), but here `Items` is a property accessed via a getter and so it is not a variable but a function result.  The only place you can typecast here, if needed, is on the *right hand* side of the assignment.

We don't know the type of `TimerList`, but assuming it is a compatible type like `TList<TTimer>` you can just assign it directly.

```
 TimerList.Items[Row] := TTimer.Create(Self);
```

If the list or array has elements of a different, compatible, but not implicitly type-castable type then you would typecast the right hand side of the assignment to match the expected type of the left hand side.

---

In the case of a plain `TObjectList` (from comments) the list elements are plain `TObject`, so any object, including a `TTimer` can be assigned to the list element as above.  Where you would need to typecast is going the other way - assigning the `TObject` back to a `TTimer` variable :

```
var 
  LMyTimer : TTimer
begin
  LMyTimer := TTimer(TimerList.Items[someIndex]);
```

Also be careful that in creating the object with `TTimer.Create(self)` you are giving `self` (probably the form?) ownership of the timer object.  By placing it into a `TObjectList` you are then also giving ownership of the object to the list.  Both will try to free the object when they are themselves freed - whichever one does so last will cause a crash, so this is a bug.

Decide which object will have ownership responsibility and implement that - an object should not have two owners!  Either have the `TObjectList` own the timer, and therefore create it with `TTimer.Create(nil)`, **or** leave the ownership with the (form?) using `TTimer.Create(self)` and use a plain `TList` instead of a `TObjectList`.

If you have a modern version of Delphi, I would strongly prefer a typed generic list, either `TList<TTimer>` or `TObjectList<TTimer>`.  This gets around the need to typecast entirely.